# How do I set my contact picture for text messaging with my Huawei Fusion?

Tags: sms

I have a Huawei Fusion and I have been trying to find out how to change the grey Android picture into my own personal one. I have had no luck finding out how to on the internet. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: open up the contact you want to add a picture. go to menu > edit contact. then click the white silhouette in blue background. the selecr a photo from album/take a photo. done!!

Comment: I mean in the messaging app. The grey Android one there when I message someone, it'll show their picture but not mine.

Comment: @Mizza can you give an screen cap in your question please?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qXfRj.jpg Where it is circled in red. Sorry for the quality. Couldn't screen shot it.

Comment: is that the stock app? seems like it is not. btw, what is your android version?

Comment: 2.3.4 What is the stock app? Does it need to be? This was in the phone when I got it.

Comment: @Miza Check my answer. A stock app is an app that came with the ROM/Phone (not a custom 3rd party one).

Comment: @Miza get us a screen cap in the following way. go into a message conversation and press and hold the power button. the a menu will appear. press capture screen. the screen cap will be saved in your memory card. upload **that image** please.

Comment: I don't have the option.

Comment: Are you sure you are on gingerbread? i.e. Android 2.3.x?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you didn't specify your Android version :(

However:

**Android 4.x Onwards:**

1. Open up your `People` app.
2. Look for an entry called `Me`.
3. Click it.
4. Click the picture at the top, and select either take picture or select from gallery.
5. Take or select a picture, crop it and your done!

**Android ≤ 4.x:**

*Note: It has been a while since I tried this - I cannot remember if it works or not*

1. Open your `Contacts` app.
2. Add a new entry, call it `Me` or just add your name in like usual.
3. Add your number FULLY. You may want to add it twice (with and without country code).
4. Add a picture to that contact you just created.
5. Voila! The picuture is now in SMS!

**Other Method:**

I noticed that on *some* contact apps, there is a 'My Contact Card' or something like that in the menu. If you have it, you can use it to set your picture as well.

Comment: I have done this. 3 times. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Miza What happens when you click the grey picture? It should take you to the contact linked to it. Android ≤ 4.x doesn't actually support pictures for yourself.

Comment: It doesn't even let me click it. I don't really see the reason they had this in the phone if you don't have the option lol